# jqgrid tree not showing like a list instead of a tree

Tags: jqgrid

I have the jqgrid configuration below that is supposed to supposed to show a Tree like structure. Instead I am getting a flat list structure displayed. Can somebody please tell me what I am missing?
Here are the versions I am using in the order listed in the html page:

```
jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js,
jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js,
jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
```

From triand.com site:

```
jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js
jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

I am also using these CSS:

```
jqueryui/1.8.14/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css,
jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css (from triand.com), 
jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css
```

in that order. My grid looks gray as opposed to the nice blue. I can't figure why.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#list").jqGrid({
        url : "/reconcile",
        datatype : "json",
        mtype : 'GET',
        colModel : [
            {name: "id",width:1,hidden:true, key:true},
            {name : 'data.key.busnDate', label : 'Business Date', hidden:false, sorttype:"date", width : 80 },
            {name : 'data.product', label : 'Product', sorttype:"string", width : 50, editable : false},
            {name : 'data.quantityBought', label : 'Quantity Bought', sorttype:"int", width : 100, editable : false},
            {"name":"level","hidden":true},
            {"name":"parent","hidden":true},
            {"name":"isLeaf","hidden":true},
            {"name":"expanded","hidden":true},
            {"name":"uiicon","hidden":true}
        ],
        treeGrid: true,
        pager : '#pager',
        loadonce:false,
        rowNum : 25,
        height: 'auto',
        rowList : [ 25,50,100,200 ],
        sortname : 'key.positionId',
        sortorder : 'asc',
        viewrecords : true,
        gridview : true,
        multiselect: false,
        multiboxonly: false,
        autoencode: true,
        caption : 'ARC Reconciliation',
        emptyrecords: "No records to found for given date!",
        jsonReader : {
                repeatitems : true,
        },
        treeIcons : {
            "plus": "ui-icon-circlesmall-plus",
            "minus": "ui-icon-circlesmall-minus",
            "leaf" : "ui-icon-document"
        },
        ExpandColumn: 'key.positionId'
    });
    jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
        edit : false,
        add : false,
        del : false,
        view : true,
        search : true
    });
    $('#datePick').datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var e = $("#list").data("events");
            if (typeof (e) !== "undefined" && typeof (e.reloadGrid) !== "undefined") {
                $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: It's important to know the test data returned from `url : "/reconcile"` (2-3 nodes and leafs). It would be helpful if you create **the demo** (in jsfiddle, for example). Moreover, you don't write which **version** of jqGrid you want to use: free or commercial. Trirand stoped providing free version after the version 4.7. **Commercial** Guriddo jqGrid version is available for [the price](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). I develop **alternative** fork [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) which is compatible with old jqGrid 4.x. Which version of jqGrid you want to use?

Comment: Last time I worked on this was 6 years ago. I am trying to showcase this grid to my new organization but I am a little rusted. I changed the URL to "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/free-jqgrid@4.14.1/js/jquery.jqgrid.min.js" to make sure I got the right version. I take from your comment that the configuration I shown above it is OK and there might be something wrong with my data. I will try to show the data to see if that helps troubleshoot my problem. I will also try to create a demo. I read somewhere a comment that said the tree could not read from static data but that might have been updated.

Comment: Don't forget to use correct CSS too: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/free-jqgrid@4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css for example. You can find some information how to use free jqGrid [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html). Additionally free jqGrid has many new features and improvements. For example, see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/additionalProperties-option-makes-unneeded-hidden-columns-in-local-scenario). You should **remove** all helper columns (`level`, `parent`, `isLeaf`, `expanded`, `uiicon` and even `id`) from `colModel`, but to hold the properties.

Comment: See [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-fa4.htm) or [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/LocalAdjacencyTree-icons.htm) examples of usage TreeGrid in free jqGrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at our new [Guriddo jqGrid documentation here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/treegrid/) in order to get answer of your problem.

Additionally to this you may want to visit or [tree grid demo here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/treegridjs/) with a lot of new features

Comment: I looked at your supplied examples and I started by just copying the configuration and getting to work that way. I realized I had an error in the data and once I fixed that It all worked and then I just added some more features. There is just couple posting that are outdated and I used those and that is why I was not getting anywhere.Thanks